# How combine the data connected by a linking/associate table into one column of a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following schema:

```
TABLE 1: People
------------------
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name ....

TABLE 2: PeopleAddresses
------------------------
peopleId INT NOT NULL,
addressId INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(peopleId,addressId)

TABLE 3: Addresses
------------------
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
street1 ....
```

With this each person can have many addresses. I want to make one query that would return data where each person gets *one* line and their addresses are all put in one column called "Addresses" and separated by a line break. For example:

```
NAME         ADDRESSES
---------    --------------------------------------
John         33 Some Rd, San Diego, CA 02111
             75 Another Rd, Santa Monica, CA 02112
---------------------------------------------------
Sam          44 Some Rd, San Diego, CA 02111
---------------------------------------------------
Jack         55 Some Rd, San Diego, CA 02111
             75 Some Rd, San Diego, CA 02111
---------------------------------------------------
```

How would I do this? Is it better to just do separate queries from PHP and then combine everything in PHP, or better to do one query with (potentially) a bunch of subqueries in it, but one DB trip?

**IMPORTANT**: I do not have permissions to create stored procs on this database.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be efficient, but I can do it:

```
SELECT 
    NAME, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        street1, 
        '\n', 
        city, 
        ',', 
        state, 
        ',', 
        zip 
        SEPARATOR '\n\n'
    ) AS Addresses 
    FROM Addresses 
    LEFT JOIN PeopleAddresses ON Addresses.id = PeopleAddresses.addressId 
    WHERE PeopleAddresses.peopleId = 23) AS Addresses 
FROM People WHERE People.id = 23;
```

This will return a row with the person's name and their addresses separated by two lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in a single query you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select 
p.id,
p.name,
group_concat(a.street1 separator ' || ') as address
from People p
inner join PeopleAddresses pa on pa.peopleId = p.id
inner join Addresses a on a.id = pa.addressId
group by p.id
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66fd1/2)**

You can choose the separator as you want.

Inner Join only will return matching data so you use left join to list the users not having any address as you can use as

```
select 
p.id,
p.name,
address
from People p
left join 
(
  select 
  pa.peopleId,
  group_concat(a.street1 separator ' || ') as address
  from PeopleAddresses pa
  inner join Addresses a on a.id = pa.addressId
  group by pa.peopleId
)t
on t.peopleId = p.id
group by p.id
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b513ad/5)**

> But remember group_concat the result is truncated to the maximum
>   length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable,
>   which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher,
>   although the effective maximum length of the return value is
>   constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet.